# Some questions about the loading of COM Tlb file

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com

I have a ASP project, which calls a C++ dll file, we called it A temporary. Then A calls a COM dll using C# coding, there is a function to use API "LoadTypeLib" to load the type library of the COM DLL, using relative path, the com dll is in same level directory of A file, but it failed with error code TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY?

Comment: I wonder if this has too little information to be reasonably answerable. Would you edit the question to show your relevant code, using the formatting tools provided?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the COM dll is registered.  If it's not the runtime will not be able to find it to make call to loadlibrary